# mysql how to save time when I need the same query but with different ordering

Tags: mysql

I have two queries but first one is with ORDER BY country DESC and the second is the same but with ORDER BY people ASC. (These queries are as examples - my queries are quite complex and time consuming). How can I save time and do not run queries twice when I am getting the same results but with different ordering only?

thank you

Comment: Do you return the same entire result set both times, just in a different order?  In that case, you could try making the inner query into a `view`, which may improve performance from caching.

Comment: If both result set are identical, and only sorted differently, then use a programming language, and use the Comparator Pattern to resort the ordering.

Comment: What are you pulling the mysql results into, and how big are the results?

Answer (score 2):

Indexing the columns on which you need to do sorting is one step of optimization